# How to know the table name inside a fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a query with union from two different tables and then on the `fetch_array` loop I would like to know from which table out of the two I am actually grabbing, anyway without adding a flag into the table's structures. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag doesn't need to be in the table, but can easily be in the query:

```
SELECT 'table1' as t, ... FROM table1
UNION
SELECT 'table2' as t, ... FROM table2

...

echo $row['t'];
```

You don't have to select fields from a table, you can simply "select a string literal" too.

Comment: then to identify it I would go `while($m=mysql_fetch_array($r)){if(isset($m['table1']){}else{} }` ?

Comment: Just use `SELECT 'table1' as t...`, the value is then available as the column `'t'`.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work when I do `SELECT *,'table'1 as t..`, `['t'] `value comes as empty, how could I select * from the table plus the new field ?

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm not sure whether MySQL supports `*` together with other fields. You *may* have to list each field individually. Which is a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you have columns with identical name in both tables you could use as

```
SELECT table1.col1 as col1, table1.col2, table1.col3 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT table2.col1 as col4, table1.col5 FROM table2
```

then when you do $data = fetch_assoc($q) you will have

```
$data["col1"] // table1.col1
$data["col2"] // table1.col2
-----------------------------
$data["col4"] //table2.col1
```